# java bluej on missing return statement

Tags: java, bluej

so when i compile it it says missing return required.

```
import java.util.*;
class p19
{
    public static int isPDA(int n)
    {
        Scanner ob=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,s=0;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                s=s+i;
            }
            if(s==n)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if(s<n)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if(s>n)
            {
                return +1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isPDA` is a method that **must return an integer** no matter which condition in your `if` is satisfied, but your *control flow statement* is *blocking* the return
... try to organize your ideas an try something like:

```
   if(s==n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(s<n)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return +1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend what @jipr311 said, if parameter "n" is <= 1, then you never enter the for loop, and thus never hit one of the return statements.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what both @jipr311 as well @DBug said, in layman's terms, the compiler needs to be assured that *whatever* happens inside the conditional statements, the method will return something. This means that in a way, the compiler doesn't care about what the "if" statements are, just that in the case (which probably won't happen if your program is designed properly) that none of the if statements are executed, *something* will be returned.

As @DBug said, a workaround could be adding an "else" statement to the if. This assures the compiler that one way or another, either the return statement in the "if" condition will execute, or the return statement in the "else" condition. Your current code doesn't assure the compiler of any such thing.